# Tomcat and URLS with percent signs in them

Tags: java, tomcat

I am finding that if I pass access tomcat with a URL with a percent sign in it (e.g.

```
http://tester:8080/blah-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/blah/getLoginURL/http%2F
```

Then tomcat seems to block the request and returns a blank response. If I remove the %gt above the request works as expected. Is there anyway to prevent this behaviour?

Edit: I thought I was using URL encoding - the above URL also causes the same failure

Comment: Use URL encoding instead of HTML encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correctly encode the URL:

```
http://tester:8080/blah-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT/blah/getLoginURL/veryr%25gt
Difference here ---------------------------------------------^^^
```

In a URI, the `%` character is special: It introduces an encoded entity. To actually put a `%` in a URI, you must use `%25` (which is the encoded entity `%`). This is called URI-encoding, although it's frequently called "[percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)".

*(Complete speculation)* If the `%gt` was meant to be a `>`, that would be `%3E`. URI encoding is a different thing from HTML character entities.